# Индекс за пределами диапазона. Ошибка. C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

Если задать массив любого размера, то при выводе массива после преобразования в dataGridView2 вылетает. Как это можно исправить?

```
private: void form(int size, int **mass) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                mass[i][j] = 2 * i - size * j;

    }
    private: void show1(int size) {
        dataGridView1->TopLeftHeaderCell->Value = "Матрица#1";
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        dataGridView1->Columns[j]->HeaderCell->Value = Convert::ToString(j + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        dataGridView1->Rows[i]->HeaderCell->Value = Convert::ToString(i + 1);

    }
    private: void show2(int size) {
        dataGridView2->TopLeftHeaderCell->Value = "Матрица#2";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            dataGridView2->Columns[j]->HeaderCell->Value = Convert::ToString(j + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            dataGridView2->Rows[i]->HeaderCell->Value = Convert::ToString(i + 1);

    }

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int y;
    int imax = 0;
    int jmax = 0;
    int size = Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDown1->Value);
    dataGridView1->ColumnCount = size;
    dataGridView1->RowCount = size;
    dataGridView1->AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode::AllCellsExceptHeaders);
    dataGridView1->AutoResizeColumns();
    show1(size);
    int **mass = new int *[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        mass[i] = new int[size];
    Random^rnd = gcnew Random();//Задает рандомный массив nxn
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                mass[i][j] = (int)rnd->Next(1000) - 500;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                dataGridView1->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value = Convert::ToString(mass[i][j]);
                dataGridView1->AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode::AllCellsExceptHeaders);
                dataGridView1->AutoResizeColumns();

            }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//Сравнение элементов массива
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if (mass[i][j]>mass[imax][jmax]) {
                imax = i; jmax = j;
            };
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {//Перемещение наибольшего эелемента в mass[i][0]
        y = mass[i][0];
        mass[i][0] = mass[imax][jmax];
        mass[i][jmax] = y;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            dataGridView2->Rows[i]->Cells[j]->Value = Convert::ToString(mass[i][j]);
            dataGridView2->AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode::AllCellsExceptHeaders);
            dataGridView2->AutoResizeColumns();

        }

}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Сообщение = Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.
Имя параметра: index
  Источник = mscorlib
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.SharedRow(Int32 rowIndex)
   в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   в Prog.n1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в c:\users\zan\source\repos\prog\prog\n1.h:строка 214
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   в Prog.General.задача1ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в c:\users\zan\source\repos\prog\prog\general.h:строка 147
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   в main(String[] args) в c:\users\zan\source\repos\prog\prog\general.cpp:строка 11
```

Comment: Я вижу в коде, что для `dataGridView1` задаётся `RowCount = size`. А сколько у вас строк в `dataGridView2`?

Comment: Спасибо. Я увидел ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить эти строки:

```
dataGridView2->ColumnCount = size;
dataGridView2->RowCount = size;
dataGridView2->AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode::AllCellsExceptHeaders);
dataGridView2->AutoResizeColumns();
show2(size);
```